# mysql triggers date

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I want to have a select statement inside the mysql trigger that has the following:

SELECT id WHERE date = TODAY'S TAKE in Y-m-d format

How do I get today's date in Y-m-d format in the select statement above?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) function.

```
 SELECT id WHERE date = CURDATE();
```